# NameError: global name 'self' is not defined -Classes

Tags: python, class

i`m trying to learn classes, and something is holding em back, i get

```
"NameError: global name 'self' is not defined"
```

the same happens to each class field. can you help me find what am i doing wrong thank you

Code:

```
class Assignment:
    def __init__(self, name, discription, deadline, grade, studentID):
        self.name = name
        self.studentID = studentID
        self.description = discription
        self.deadline = deadline
        self.grade = grade

    def __str__(self):
        return "studentID:" + self.studentID + "assignment name:" + self.name +" description:" + self.description + " deadline:" + self.deadline + " grade:" + self.grade

    def validation(self):
        errors= []
        if self.studendID == "":
            errors.append("No existing student ID.")  
        if self.description == "":
            errors.append("No existing description.")
        if self.deadline == "":
            errors.append("No existing deadline.")      
        if self.deadline == "":
            errors.append("No existing deadline.")    
        return errors

    @staticmethod
    def dummyAssignments():
        ret = []
        for studentID in range(100, 121):
            print "sda"
            a = Assignment(self, name, discription, deadline, grade, studentID)
            ret.append(a)            
        return ret   

def testAssigment():
    a = Assignment("","","","","")
    print a



testAssigment()   
print Assignment.dummyAssignments()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass `self` when instantiating your class.

```
Assignment(self, name, discription, deadline, grade, studentID)
```

should be

```
Assignment(name, discription, deadline, grade, studentID)
```

The error is letting you know you are trying to use a var `self` that is not defined in either local or global scope.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
a = Assignment(self, name, discription, deadline, grade, studentID)
```

This is in a `@staticmethod`, so `self` isn't defined.

Indeed, none of those values are defined, come to think of it -- except `studentID`.

Answer (score 2):

The *dummyAssignments* static method only has studentIDs but not any of the other fields.

Try giving default values to each of the fields:

```
class Assignment:
    def __init__(self, name='', discription='', deadline='', grade='', studentID =''):
        self.name = name
        self.studentID = studentID
        self.description = discription
        self.deadline = deadline
        self.grade = grade

    def __str__(self):
        return "studentID:" + self.studentID + "assignment name:" + self.name +" description:" + self.description + " deadline:" + self.deadline + " grade:" + self.grade

    def validation(self):
        errors= []
        if self.studendID == "":
            errors.append("No existing student ID.")  
        if self.description == "":
            errors.append("No existing description.")
        if self.deadline == "":
            errors.append("No existing deadline.")      
        if self.deadline == "":
            errors.append("No existing deadline.")    
        return errors

    @staticmethod
    def dummyAssignments():
        ret = []
        for studentID in range(100, 121):
            print "sda"
            a = Assignment(studentID=studentID)
            ret.append(a)            
        return ret   

def testAssigment():
    a = Assignment("","","","","")
    print a



testAssigment()   
print Assignment.dummyAssignments()
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class decleration:

```
class Assignment:
```

change it to

```
class Assignment():
```

or

```
class Assignment(object):
```